# Can two ascx files share the same code file?

Tags: c#, user-controls, ascx

I have two files:

```
SomeUserControl.en.ascx
SomeUserControl.fr.ascx
```

I'd like them to share the same code file:

```
SomeUserControl.ascx.cs
```

This is on a NON-compiled site and the files are IDENTICAL except for the language. In THIS case, using Localization is NOT an option.

Will this work:

```
CodeFile="SomeUserControl.ascx.cs"
```

These are not compiled files... but rather xcopy deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, we have a project like that. Look for this attribute on your aspx/ascx page:

```
<%@  ... CodeBehind="YourClassFile.ascx.cs" ... %>
```

Comment: Have you run into any gotchas doing this?

Comment: @Atømix If your not familiar with it, it can be a little confusing when you see a bunch of files in solution explorer with no corresponding code files. Other then that no, it works fine.